# De-summarize a dataframe with a column that contains lists in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a question about de-summarize a dataframe in R. I have the following dataframe:

```
  A  B
  ----
  X  c(1,2,4)
  C  c(1,4,3)
  V  c(5,3,2)
  B  c(2,4,5,6)
```

So, in the B column are vectors.
I want to turn this dataframe into the following:

```
  B  A
  ----
  1  X
  1  C
  2  X
  2  V
  2  B
  3  C
  3  V
  4  X
  4  C
  4  B
  5  B
  6  B
```

Maybe someone has an idea how I can convert this table?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `unnest` from `tidyr` to unnest the `list` column and then `arrange` by column 'B'

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
unnest(df1, B) %>%
    arrange(B) %>%
    select(B, A)
# A tibble: 13 x 2
#       B A    
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 X    
# 2     1 C    
# 3     2 X    
# 4     2 V    
# 5     2 B    
# 6     3 C    
# 7     3 V    
# 8     4 X    
# 9     4 C    
#10     4 B    
#11     5 V    
#12     5 B    
#13     6 B
```

---

Or create a named `list` i.e. name the `list` column 'B' with 'A' elements and `stack` it to a two column data.frame in `base R`

```
with(df1, stack(setNames(B, A)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("X", "C", "V", "B"), B = list(c(1, 2, 4), 
    c(1, 4, 3), c(5, 3, 2), c(2, 4, 5, 6))), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```